# Error handling function for any type in Go

Tags: generics, go

I am trying to abstract the following pattern that seems to occur quite a lot, but the only way I can think of doing so is through a generic function:

```
func DoStuff () MyType {
    result, err := SomeProcess()  // returns MyType
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return result // or do something else with it
}
```

Here's my solution:

```
func FailOnError(value interface{}, err error) interface{} {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return value
}

func DoStuff () MyType {
    return FailOnError(SomeProcess())
}
```

The problem is that I don't have compile-time type safety, and if I want to do anything further with the result I need to explicitly type cast it, e.g.

```
type MyType struct {
    value int
}

// Assuming a function with this signature
func GetItem() (MyType, error)

func Add () MyType {
    item := MyType(FailOnError(GetItem()))
}
```

This is ok, I guess, but rather inelegant. Also, it means manually enforcing types which is always somewhat fragile and a potential performance hit.

Is there a better, or more idiomatic way of doing this?

**Edit:** Since this seems to be a hated question, how about I use the following example instead:

```
func Identity(x interface{}) interface{} {
    return x
}
```

Usage would need to be:

```
x = int(Identity(1))
y = MyType(Identity(MyType{value}))
```

And there is nothing stopping me from doing

```
x = int(Identity(MyType{value}))
```

`Identity` is intentionally trivial, but need not necessarily be so. I could be, for example, and method designed to do some logging, or mutate an object and return it.  Another situations I have is where I want to do some work on some types defined in various external libraries - they are similar enough that I can write a single function to handle all of them, but they don't share an interface.

Comment: You can generate functions (basically automated copy-paste) per required type.

Comment: If it's for error handling, wrapping them inside "generic" function is not idiomatic in go.

Comment: Not sure what's so heinous about this question that it's got 3 downvotes, but I'll try to ask it in another way that might not invoke such ire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better, or more idiomatic way of doing this?

Yes: Handle the error. Log.Fatal is not error handling. If fataling is really the right thing: Encapsulate fataling only.

Make fataling on error a function, not the calling and please stay away from `interface{}`:

```
func abortOnError(err error) {
    if err == nil {return}
    log.Fatal(err)
}

func whatever() int {
    x, err := someOp()
    abortOnError(err)
    return x+2
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. In the cases I'm dealing with, I frequently need to fatal when an error occurs. This would not always be the case but I need it often enough that I want to encapsulate it.

Comment: See the updated answer: You encapsulate your action on the error _only_. Never on the whole call. Just take a look at how the stdlibrary or any substantial Go code does.